# When doing structure equation modeling, CFI and TLI=1, RMSEA=0, what should I do?

Tags: r, stata

I have run a mediation analysis using SEM and have obtained a CFI and TLI of 1 and an RMSEA of 0. Based on these results, it appears that the model is fitting the data perfectly. However, I am aware that having CFI and TLI equal to 1 and RMSEA equal to 0 is an indication that the model may be overfitting the data. I would like to take the appropriate steps to ensure the validity of my results. Can you provide guidance on how to proceed and what additional measures I should consider in evaluating the model's fit?

I have conducted further analysis on my SEM model by reducing the number of variables to only include my X, Y and mediator. However, I am still obtaining a CFI and TLI of 1 and an RMSEA of 0.

Below are screenshots of my results (model fit measures and regression results).
[image: Model fit]

[image: Regressions]

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the concrete model it is hard to judge why your model fit the data perfectly. However, given your description, I assume that you have fitted a model in which Y is regressed on X and M, and M is regressed on X. Using lavaan syntax:

```
    Y ~ X + M
    M ~ X
```

If this is correct, then you have estimated a model that has zero degrees of freedom. The model thus fits the data perfectly by definition.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you so much for your comments! I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a moment to review the updated results and let me know if there are any further suggestions or concerns. Thanks!

Comment: Hi NotInSofa, as written in my answer above, you fit a fully identified model (the degrees of freedom are zero) and this explains why the fit indices are 'perfect' (RMSEA = 0, CFI = 1, etc.). Best Stefan

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your response. Could you further explain why my model is fully identified?